# OpenIddict authorization request not handled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I'm trying out [OpenIddict 3.0](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) for use in a SSO app. I followed the steps in the documentation, created an Authorize controller, and added a test application. When I try to connect to authorize I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The authorization request was not handled. To handle authorization requests, create a class implementing 'IOpenIddictServerHandler' and register it using 'services.AddOpenIddict().AddServer().AddEventHandler()'.
>   Alternatively, enable the pass-through mode to handle them at a later stage.

I can't find anything in the documentation or sample apps that explains what this means. What am I missing?

---

Here's my code so far. In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(o =>
    {
        o.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    })
    .AddServer(o =>
    {
        o.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");
        o.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize");

        o.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

        o.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email);

        o.AcceptAnonymousClients();
        o.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
            .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
        o.UseAspNetCore()
            .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
            .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();
    })
    .AddValidation(o =>
    {
        o.UseLocalServer();
        o.UseAspNetCore();
    });
```

And test app description:

```
var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
{
    ClientId = "test-app",
    DisplayName = "Test Application",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { new Uri("https://oidcdebugger.com/debug") },
    RedirectUris = { new Uri("https://oidcdebugger.com/debug") }
};
```

I'm testing with the [OpenID Connect debugger](https://oidcdebugger.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle authorization requests in a MVC controller, you must tell OpenIddict's ASP.NET Core host to use the pass-through mode, exactly like what you did for the token endpoint:

```cs
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.UseAspNetCore()
               .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough() // Add this line.
               .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
               .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();
    });
```